# How to make the windows' title bars transparent in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes, titlebar, transparency

(I'm new to Ubuntu, and Linux systems in general.)

Hello! I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with the default theme that it came with, and I want to make the title bar in every window - transparent.
So it would look **similar** to Windows 7's "Aero Glass Theme".

So, I would like to ask, whether it is possible, and if it is, then how should I do it?

I've not found any tutorials about this topic, except of outdated tutorials for old version of Ubuntu, when it has been using Unity, rather than GNOME like now, and as I understood, these tutorials won't be supported in GNOME, and also, they didn't work for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these CSS rules, but don't expect it to work with all applications.
Open the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (if the file doesn't exist, create it), and put write this CSS code inside it:

```css
* {
  background-clip:content-box;
}
headerbar {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.titlebar {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Save the file and in the terminal run this command:

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

Whether it works or not, also depend upon your current theme. This trick successfully worked for some of my applications:
[image]

Comment: Thank you!
Since then, I moved to OpenSUSE with KDE :)
But I'm sure your answer will help others!
Thank you very much!